# how does namespace and private variables work in assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, namespaces

how does it work? are the variables stored in special registers or memory? im looking at the register/memory windows in visual but i cant understand it :(

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace first
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 10;
}

namespace second
{
  double x = 3.1416;
  double y = 2.7183;
}

int main () {
  using first::x;
  using second::y;
  cout << x << endl;
  cout << y << endl;
  cout << first::y << endl;
  cout << second::x << endl;
  return 0;
}


class CRectangle {
    int x, y;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area (void);
  private:
    int param;
  } rect;
```

Comment: Try a search for "name mangling"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the machine's perspective, there's nothing different about `private` or `namespace`. Those are just identifiers for the compiler. That is, the compiler enforces access rules, which is why you get compiler errors for doing something you shouldn't. The binary code the compiler ultimately produces, however, doesn't make any distinction about what the data is.

Comment: so for a private variable, it isnt stored in any "special place"?

Comment: @JoeChen Correct. A `private` variable is just a designation to the compiler to prevent unauthorized access. So if you were wondering, `private` can't be used for safely storing passwords, etc; you'll need encryption for that.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler takes

```
namespace first
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 10;
}

namespace second
{
  double x = 3.1416;
  double y = 2.7183;
}
```

and effectively produces assembly code which works something like this:

```
_first@@x:     dd      5
_first@@y:     dd      10
_second@@x:    dq      3.1416
_second@@y:    dq      2.7183
```

In case you are not familiar with assembly language, these four statements each reserve memory, two for 32-bit integers, and two for a floating point values, and assign labels to them.  A label is a memory address.

Note that the namespace qualifies each variable name.  The `@`  in itself it has no meaning, but escapes the namespace and variable name to isolate unusually named `C++` language variables.  Assembly language identifiers typically allow a greater range of characters in them than high level languages, convenient in usages such as this.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are used as direction for compiler, as actual var names and method/class names have different name after compilation, so namespace name is not used.